# I have an error that i don't find my specific color on Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, colors, find

I am working on my project which uses Access, take a problem.

This project include 3 tables, so these are PARCA , KATALOG, and TEDARIKCI.

And their columns PARCA; PID,Padi,Renk
KATALOG has 3 columns: TID,PID,maliyet
and last one TEDARIKCI has 3 columns TID,tadi,adres

I want to find only red color parca , so I use the code :

```
SELECT T.TID
FROM PARCA AS P, TEDARIKCI AS T, KATALOG AS K
WHERE P.PID=K.PID AND K.TID=T.TID AND P.Renk NOT IN('RED');
```

If I use the "IN('RED')" ,There is an error but If I use this, there isn't any error and there are the other colors which is used by other TEDARIKCI.

So How can I solve the problem. 
Thank you

Sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

What if you change your SQL statement a bit to make the joins explicit and use `WHERE P.Renk = 'RED'` instead of `P.Renk IN ('RED')`

```
SELECT T.TID
FROM PARCA AS P
INNER JOIN KATALOG AS K
ON P.PID=K.PID
INNER JOIN TEDARIKCI AS T
ON K.TID=T.TID 
WHERE P.Renk ='RED';
```